# Better buttons for iPhone game ? Non square?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

Sorry if a stupid question, but I currently have an iPhone game which uses UI Kit butons for it's menu interface with a custom background. How could I improve the look and feel of my buttons - e.g how can I use custom non square shapes ?

Thanks all,

Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIButton actually has support for non-rectangular shapes.  Simply use an image file that has an alpha channel (such as PNG) that defines the bounds of the button.